# Raw Socket Linux send/receive a packet

Tags: c, sockets, networking, send, recv

Have some problems in receiving packets.
I can receive and read incoming packets, but I think i do not get a handshake with any host.
I only want to send a packet to a remote computer with an open port on receiving an answer to see the TTL(time to live) and the window size.
Does anyone have an idea where the errors are? <strike>(I don't have very deep knowledge in C programming)</strike>

CODE:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

struct pseudohdr {
    u_int32_t src_addr;
    u_int32_t dst_addr;
    u_int8_t padding;
    u_int8_t proto;
    u_int16_t length;
};

struct data_4_checksum {
    struct pseudohdr pshd;
    struct tcphdr tcphdr;
    char payload[1024];
};
unsigned short comp_chksum(unsigned short *addr, int len) {
    long sum = 0;

    while (len > 1) {
        sum += *(addr++);
        len -= 2;
    }

    if (len > 0)
        sum += *addr;

    while (sum >> 16)
        sum = ((sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16));

    sum = ~sum;

    return ((u_short) sum);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sock, bytes, on = 1;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct iphdr *ip;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    struct sockaddr_in to;
    struct pseudohdr pseudoheader;
    struct data_4_checksum tcp_chk_construct;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s ", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "<dest-addr>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket() failed");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("socket() ok\n");
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt() failed");
        return 2;
    }else{
        printf("setsockopt() ok\n");
    }

    ip = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
    tcp = (struct tcphdr*) (buffer + sizeof(struct tcphdr));

    int iphdrlen = sizeof(struct iphdr);
    int tcphdrlen = sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    int datalen = 0;
    printf("Typecasting ok\n");

    ip->frag_off = 0;
    ip->version = 4;
    ip->ihl = 5;
    ip->tot_len = htons(iphdrlen + tcphdrlen);
    ip->id = 0;
    ip->ttl = 40;
    ip->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    ip->saddr = inet_addr("192.168.165.135");
    ip->daddr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    ip->check = 0;

    tcp->source     = htons(12345);
    tcp->dest       = htons(80);
    tcp->seq        = random();
    tcp->doff       = 5;
    tcp->ack        = 0;
    tcp->psh        = 0;
    tcp->rst        = 0;
    tcp->urg        = 0;
    tcp->syn        = 1;
    tcp->fin        = 0;
    tcp->window     = htons(65535);

    pseudoheader.src_addr = ip->saddr;
    pseudoheader.dst_addr = ip->daddr;
    pseudoheader.padding = 0;
    pseudoheader.proto = ip->protocol;
    pseudoheader.length = htons(tcphdrlen + datalen);

    tcp_chk_construct.pshd = pseudoheader;
    tcp_chk_construct.tcphdr = *tcp;

    int checksum = comp_chksum((unsigned short*) &tcp_chk_construct,
            sizeof(struct pseudohdr) + tcphdrlen + datalen);

    tcp->check = checksum;

    printf("TCP Checksum: %i\n", checksum);
    printf("Destination : %i\n", ntohs(tcp->dest));
    printf("Source: %i\n", ntohs(tcp->source));

    to.sin_addr.s_addr = ip->daddr;
    to.sin_family = AF_INET;
    to.sin_port = tcp->dest;

    bytes = sendto(sock, buffer, ntohs(ip->tot_len), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &to,
            sizeof(to));

    if (bytes == -1) {
        perror("sendto() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    printf("TTL= %d\n", ip->ttl);
    printf("Window= %d\n", tcp->window);
    printf("ACK= %d\n", tcp->ack);
    printf("%s:%d\t --> \t%s:%d \tSeq: %d \tAck: %d\n",
                    inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*) &ip->saddr), ntohs(tcp->source),
                    inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *) &ip->daddr), ntohs(tcp->dest),
                    ntohl(tcp->seq), ntohl(tcp->ack_seq));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: with incoming packets i mean, there are other incoming from everywhere but not from i need

Comment: why to parse the packet? i was trying to get some response on a clean unix machine under vmware. when i sended a packet manually, i got what i need. but if i simply wait nothing happens. under real system there are packets comming in. but these are from somewhere else.

Comment: I just re-posted my comments as an actual answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Layer 2 => Data Link? I thought for layer 2 there are packet sockets. In my code I use typecast to access the buffer in the right way. And you don't get my problem. My problem is, that I'am receiving packets. Program works  but I'am not receiving an answer to my packet I have send.

Comment: root@***:/********# ./OS_Sniffer 141.28.78.142

Comment: socket() ok
setsockopt() ok
Typecasting ok
TCP Checksum: 350
Destination : 80
Source: 12345
TTL= 52
Window= 31232
ACK= 1
67.228.168.221:80  -->  67.228.168.221:60806  Seq: -1525233884  Ack: -46020552

Comment: sorry, typo. It's Layer 3.

Comment: no prob. please look at the output. it works, but wrong :)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your output. The negative values? Print them using the unsigned format specifier, `%u`. Other than that, could you highlight?

Comment: 67.228.168.221:80  --> 67.228.168.221:60806 But I need something from 141.28.78.142

Comment: I'am working with C only for few weeks. Thats why its little bit difficult for me

Comment: Understandable, but you're doing great. Please, take a look at point 4 in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You're receiving and storing packets in `buffer`, but you're printing data from `ip` and `tcp` without parsing that buffer. You should parse the packet from `buffer` **after receiving** it, and **before printing**.
2. Your code assumes all packets are TCP, which is not the case. RAW sockets only support Layer 3 protocols (IP, ICMP, etc). In other words, using `IPPROTO_TCP` is misleading when creating a RAW socket. Stick to `IPPROTO_IP`, and add the necessary conditions to your code for each protocol you care about (TCP, UDP, etc). This happens to be working because the Linux Kernel validates the protocol number, and fallbacks to `IPPROTO_IP`. However, this might not work in other systems.
3. Review if your network communication is using the correct byte-order. The network-byte-order is Big-Endian, while the host-byte-order  depends on your architecture, so you may need to convert multi-byte fields back and forth.
4. Your `tcp->seq` might have an invalid value, because TCP only accepts values up to 65535, while `random()` returns values from 0 to `RAND_MAX` (0x7fffffff). Try `tcp->seq = htonl(random() % 65535);`
5. Your offset calculation for the TCP header is incorrect. It should be `sizeof(struct iphdr)` rather than `sizeof(struct tcphdr)`.

Comment: Is it even possible to receive TCP or UDP packets with a raw socket? I thought these incoming packets were always passed to the TCP and UDP drivers.

Comment: @Barmar it's possible. The kernel delivers a copy of each datagram to every process that has created a RAW socket that matches the datagram protocol.

Comment: Found the error! Its the buffer, because i was sending some rubbish to the remote host. Therefore i could not receive an answer. Correction: char buffer[1024]={0};

Comment: Regarding your point 2, trying to use `IPPROTO_IP` results in an error `Protocol not supported` for me, when calling `socket()` on linux. Using either `IPPROTO_TCP` or `IPPROTO_RAW` works, although I didn't check whether it filters TCP packets or not.

Comment: @jweyrich, ICMP is layer 3?

Comment: @Pacerier yep. It's encapsulated in IPv4/6 packets. It's part of the IP though.

Answer (score 0):

```
ip = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
tcp = (struct tcphdr*) (buffer + sizeof(struct tcphdr)); //This is wrong
```

Here to get array index of tcp header in `buffer`, you need to add `sizeof(struct iphdr)` to `buffer` like mentioned below.

```
ip = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
tcp = (struct tcphdr*) (buffer + sizeof(struct iphdr)); //This is correct
```

Comment: Is not correct as it should use the `ip->ihl * 4` to know the header size.